# Simple Way to Map Latitude Longitude Ranges to Coordinate Values in R?

Tags: r, data-science, geospatial, raster

I have a dataframe that contains information about 3000 hospitals, along with a dataframe containing instances of 1million+ vaccinations.  Im trying to map each vaccination to either a hospital included in the hospitals data or simply a vaccination site thats not a hospital.

All hospitals in the hospital dataframe have a geolocation field of latitude and longitude coordinates.  The vaccinations dataframe also has latitude and longitude columns.  The issue is that a lot of times these coordinates aren't exact, so I can't simply map them directly to lat long values in the hospitals dataset.  Therefore Im creating a small spatial buffer and lat long range for each of the hospitals geolocation and looking to see if the vaccinations fall within those ranges.  The issue is that the code Im running is taking a while and Im sure theres a simpler way to do what Im trying to do.

Thanks!

```
total_in_hospital_vaccinations <- 0
total_out_hospital_vaccinations <- 0
hospitals$vaccinations <- 0
for(i in 1:NROW(hospitals)){
    hospital <- hospital[i,]
    name <- hospital$name
    in_range <- vaccinations[(vaccinations$long >= hospital$longitude_low & vaccinations$long <= hospital$longitude_high
       & vaccination$lat <= hospital$latitude_high & vaccination$lat >= hospital$latitude_low),]
    hospitals[(hospitals$name == name),]$vaccinations <- NROW(in_range)
    total_in_hospital_vaccinations <- total_in_hospital_vaccinations + NROW(in_range)
total_out_hospital_vaccinations <- NROW(vaccinations) - total_in_hospital_vaccinations
```

Comment: Can you post a small reproducible example and show expected output based on that?

Comment: This type of question has come up on SO before, and I believe one of the solutions used `outer(seq_len(nrow(df1)), seq_len(nrow(df2)), function(i, j) geosphere::distHaversine(df1[i,], df2[j,]))` to get the distances between each of your vaccination sites and each of your hospitals. From there, find the column with the min-distance and you'll know to which hospital it is likely to belong. This is a different approach than you've done here, where I believe you create a square around each hospital. (Just offered as an option.)

Comment: Another option closer to what you are doing, but following the same logic than @r2evans proposes, would be to create a circular buffer of a given distance around your hospitals using `rgeos::gBuffer()` then determine which vaccination points belong to a given _hospital+buffer_ employing `rgeos::gIntersection()` or `raster::intersect()`